# Will i still have my profile already loaded on my Xbox if i change the hardrive?

Tags: xbox-360

If i change my Xbox 360 harddrive, will my profile still be on my system or will I have to re-download it?

Comment: There is no 'internal storage' to store your profile in the Xbox. In other words, everything permanent is stored on the hard drive.

Comment: Hi @user53932 I suggest you add which XBox 360 version you have.  Most likely, the answer to your question is as deutschZuid suggests.  The slight exception is that some XBox model have an internal hard drive - but in that case it's fairly *non-removable*, so I'm guessing from your question wording you are dealing with one of the older models.  Storing your profile in the cloud is pretty easy, so re-downloading it is not a big deal really.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to redownload the profile unless you have a [Hard Drive Transfer Kit](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Xbox-360-Hard-Drive-Transfer-Cable/productID.253743300).